# Is helping others is obligatory in islam

Tags: helping

Assalam alaikum ,I came across one statement.,
Imam Ja'far as-Sadiq (a.s.) says:
"He is not a believer who inspite of being capable avoids helping his brother in need; Allah also leaves him on his own and does not help him in this world nor the Hereafter."
And also
Allah does not help a believer who does not help his brother in faith and leaves him on his own.
Is this true ... Will allah leave me just like that.. if I didn't help... Because when I came to know this verse I lost my faith totally.. and cant able to make dua becoz thinking that allah will not help me ,also I can't able to make tawba for that .. knowing it's optional .Sadaqah is optional right??.. pls help me .I can't focus on my studies
properly and Fully by came to know
this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, helping others is considered an obligatory act in Islam. It is a core principle of the faith and is emphasized in various verses of the Quran and teachings of the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him). Muslims are encouraged to help others in need, whether they are Muslims or non-Muslims, and to do so without seeking any material reward or recognition. This can take various forms, such as charitable donations, volunteering, offering a helping hand, or even offering a kind word or gesture. The ultimate goal of helping others is to seek the pleasure of Allah and to earn His blessings.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer ..but I want to know.. we can't able to help each and everyone right.. or if we are busy walking on road.. we did not give money to the beggar.. is this a sin?.. Also some people take advantage of me to offer them help , eventhough thay can able to do.. like in studies.. eventhough they can able to get notes or some other stuffs ,they ask from me without spending their time..and here me spending much time to get that stuffs.. so what to do in this case,can we refuse.?may I know allah will not help means.. he will not do any help for me..? Means all my prayers then?.

Comment: but if friends or any person asks help,.. we can do as it is a good deed..but is it compulsory to do??.. if not then is it a sin? .. and in some cases .. we can't just go and help them..as they didn't value that.. in that case is it ok, only when they ask help..we can do

Comment: @Aisha Zakah is a pillar of islam, and you can do zakat. Feed money to the poor, and you can also do other compulsoary deeds similarly to deed zakat.